# qForms select by input ID rather than name

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form that is using qForm form validation.  qForm by default looks at an input's name for validating, but I would like to select by ID instead.

```
 objForm["CmeChanges"].required = true;
```

Is there a way to select the ID attribute rather than the name?

http://www.pengoworks.com/qforms/docs/examples/